# Using block diagram reduction rules, convert the block diagram to a simple loop and determine the transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, block-diagram

[image]

I don't know how how to reduce after the branch point next to H1 from which it is connected to 2 summation points.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  People are keen to help here, but with exercises such as this, you need to set out what you have been able to understand, and which particular steps or concepts you are struggling with. Questions which show little independent effort will tend to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

> *I don't know how how to reduce after the branch point next to H1 from
> which it is connected to 2 summation points.*

You mean this one: -

[image]

Well ultimately, to "reduce", it sometimes means you have to "enlarge" in order to simplify: -

[image]

Now can you solve it?